# IntelliJ indents } the same as the contents between { and }

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, code-formatting, dartfmt

I'm using IntelliJ and the Dart plugin (version 213.5744.122), and for some reason IntelliJ insists on creating a weird indentation in the following code:

```
Expanded(
  child: TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'CA', border: OutlineInputBorder(),),
    controller: caController,
    onChanged: (_){
      setState((){});
      },
    enabled: true,
  ),
),
```

Notice how the closing `}` of the `onChanged` handler is indented one step further in than a sane person would put it. Personally, I would normally unindent the `}` one step. If that's not possible for some reason, as a very last resort I would at least indent the contents between `{` and `}` one step further than the `}`. But IntelliJ insists on indenting both the content and the `}` equally.

If I try running `Reformat code with dart format` on the code, it fixes the indentation. So it seems to be a problem with IntelliJ, not the Dart formatter?

Also, if I completely remove any contents between `{` and `}` like this

```
onChanged: (_){}
```

and then place the cursor between `{` and `}` and hit Enter, it formats it correctly:

```
onChanged: (a){

},
```

How can I fix this?? There are no code style settings available for Dart in the IntelliJ settings, so what can I do?

Comment: IntelliJ sometimes does different formatting when `,` are involved. See how the only difference between your last two code blocks is the comma? Let me know if removing it changes anything.

Comment: @GabrielPizarro Unfortunately the comma doesn't make any difference.

Comment: The other trick I use is to learn the formatting shortcut `Ctrl/Cmd`+`Alt/Option`+`L`. It should do the same thing as `Reformat code with dart format`. You can also submit a bug report in [the official bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?q=Subsystem:%20Dart) if you'd like